# Android - Canvas that (virtually) extends off the end of the phone

Tags: android, canvas

I have seen many iPhone and iPad note apps where there is a drawing canvas, and if you use 2 fingers and drag, the canvas itself moves, like it is endless. They can go to a different part of the canvas, but still be on the same note/page.

I was wondering if this is possible on Android, and if there are any tutorials out there?

I don't want it to be endless, but extend more than just the single part of the screen.

Comment: yea I mam sure you could do this on android.  I have not seen any tutorials or anything but I would imagine you would use a dirty rectangle to extend a canvas off of the max phone width and height.  and then on touch change the coordinates of the dirty rectangle to correspond the changes of the on touch drag.